# ASP.Net Webforms Data Annotation Validation in .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, validation, .net-4.0, webforms

I am using asp.net webforms with some HTML input controls and binding these controls with knockout viewmodel. When the knockout viewmodel is submitted to server after serializing and mapped to its equivalent server side business model, is there any way to validate server side business model using validation attributes/fluent api or something.

The question is, how to server side validate individual properties of business entities in .net 4 webforms?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to validate your Knockout model server-side before it's saved? The question gets a little confusing towards the end.

Comment: @dgarbacz I have edited to clarify my question. Thanks

Comment: @Nexus23,what is the correct answer of your question ?